# What are the most restrictive aws resource name limitations (e.g. characters and length)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, naming

Different resources in aws, such as S3 buckets, lambdas and roles, have different maximum lengths and different character sets which they accept.

Is there a very restrictive resource name, which, if you follow it, you will also be obeying the restrictions of all other resources?

I'm looking for a set of constraints which will obey every kind of restriction enforced by all resource groups, globally, yet also be as permissive as possible.

The ideal answer would be a nice, unambiguous regular expression.

Comment: While I don't have a complete set of resource name restrictions, the ones for S3 bucket names are already pretty limiting: 3-63 characters, limited set of special characters as allowed in domain names (e.g. `.` and `-`, but no `_`): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html#bucketnamingrules

Comment: @Dunedan counter-example: lambda does not allow `.`

Comment: Well, that's no counter example, that's than just an additional limitation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## 1. AWS Lambda

> Function name must contain only letters, numbers, hyphens, or underscores
>
> This field is too long. Maximum length is 140 characters.
>
> This field is too short. Minimum length is 1 character.

source: AWS Lambda "Create Function" Page & API [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateFunction.html#API_CreateFunction_RequestSyntax).

## 2. S3 Bucket:

> Bucket name must NOT contain uppercase characters or underscores
>
> Bucket name must be between 3 and 63 characters long

source: AWS S3 "Create Bucket" Page & API [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html#bucketnamingrules).

## 3. RDS

> Must contain 1 to 63 alphanumeric characters or hyphens.
>
> First character must be a letter.
>
> Cannot end with a hyphen or contain two consecutive hyphens.

source: AWS RDS [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.Constraints)

So adding only the 3 services above we can conclude that it's best to be:

> Only lowercase alphanumeric characters and hyphens.
>
> Minimum of 3 characters and maximum of 63.
>
> First character must be a letter, cannot end with a hyphen or contain two consecutive hyphens.

I'd also suggest subtracting a common prefix (i.e. company name initials, "google-") from the maximum length to avoid running into issues when trying to create a bucket (or any AWS wide name) that could happen with a valid common name = "john"

Also looking at the IAM username and roles length restrictions (found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-limits.html#reference_iam-limits-entity-length)), nothing seems to conflict with the above conclusion.

## Regex #1 (for advanced regex engines w/ lookahead support)

```
 /(?=.{3,63}$)(?!-)(?!.*--)[a-z0-9-]+(?<!-)/
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897392/1772245) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115363/1772245) for better understand the regex above.

## Regex #2

```
 /(^[a-z\d]{1,2}((-[a-z\d])|([a-z\d]{1,2})){0,30}[a-z\d]$)|(^[‌​a-z\d]((-[a-z\d])|([‌​a-z\d]{1,2})){0,30}[‌​a-z\d-]?[a-z\d]$)/
```

Comment: Thanks, @mostafazh. Did you check any other resources? E.g. IAM roles? How do you know there aren't other resources to consider? I note that you've eliminated underscore and hyphen from your final ruleset. I know S3 buckets eliminate underscore (although you've excluded this information), but why eliminate hyphens? Remember the correct answer will also be maximally permissive. I've amended the question to request a regex as the answer.

Comment: won't work since it doesn't match something like `asdasd-d` or `a-d`

Comment: Here is a modified version which allows the odd character to be either at the start or the end: `(^[a-z\d]{1,2}((-[a-z\d])|([a-z\d]{1,2})){0,30}[a-z\d]$)|(^[a-z\d]((-[a-z\d])|([a-z\d]{1,2})){0,30}[a-z\d-]?[a-z\d]$)` . Unfortunately, it's twice as long, but I don't see a way around that with a straight-forward regex which is supported by languages like javascript.

Comment: Actually `dd-dd4-d0ss-sdd-a-d-fd3` matches. My regex is basically the combination of https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897392/1772245 `(?!-)(?!.*--)[a-z0-9-]+(?<!-)` and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115363/1772245 `(?=.{3,63}$)` which is basically lookahead regex

Comment: Cool. Thanks for looking into this! Please add my latest regex as an alternative for people using regex engines which don't support lookaheads and I will accept this answer.

Comment: ALB Target group names have a maximum length of 32 characters: `Target group name 'test-stack-type-rainy-alb-target-group' cannot be longer than '32' characters (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError`. Presumably, Regex #1 can simply be altered by changing the length constraint to `{3, 32}`, as for #2... not sure.

Comment: ElastiCache cluster names have a maximum length of 20 characters: `The parameter CacheClusterIdentifier is not a valid identifier because it is longer than 20 characters.` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html#cfn-elasticache-cachecluster-clustername. That would make the size restriction `{3, 20}`.

Comment: It looks like you accidentally left “[a-z0-9-]” in the regex, but as you mentioned only letters and hyphens should be allowed, so the “0-9” part should be removed.

Comment: Hanse00 you mean the first regex?