# AWS CloudFormation: Seeking the cleanest way to ensure custom resource names don't exceed the length limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I'm working on a complex codebase that stands up many diverse AWS resources using CloudFormation. However, the codebase applies custom naming for each resource in the stack that often causes deployments to fail because the names get too long.

Unfortunately, each resource type seems to have its own bespoke character limit, so manually updating the codebase to hardcode the limits in all the right places is an endless game of whackamole. We're talking about things like load balancers, SageMaker endpoints, IAM Roles, Secrets, ...

Is there some nice, simple, ideally automatic way to truncate the names of resources that exceed the limit for each resource? For context I'm using AWS's Python CDK.

Comment: I use Typescript CDK and never faced that error, usually the names are generated according to the max amount of chars possible per service. Could that be a bug from the AWS Python CDK library? Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Do you mean "explicit" resource names (e.g. `bucket_name = "my_long_bucket_name"`)?  A Custom Resource is a [CloudFormation feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that is [supported by the CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the most restrictive aws resource name limitations (e.g. characters and length)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052869/what-are-the-most-restrictive-aws-resource-name-limitations-e-g-characters-and)

Comment: Basically - no, there is no nice and automatic way, you have to either go for the pattern that would satisfy all requirements across all services via trial and error, or write custom rules for different resource types.